# Is there a way to trigger an event with jQuery (or the regular DOM API) without invoking any handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dom

I want to trigger a form submit, but not have my usual handlers for that form's submit be called.  I could just unregister any listeners, before calling, but that feels ugly (and specific to form submits since they're the only type of event that I can guarantee will be the last to occur).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to unregister your event handlers; they will not be invoked when you fire the event programmatically...

```
document.forms[0].onsubmit = function() {
  alert("You will not see this");
  return false;
}
document.forms[0].submit();
```

However, if you have a jQuery object, be sure to call the submit function of the underlying DOM element...

```
$("form")[0].submit();
```